# youtube video play in background html files

Tags: php, html, youtube-api

I was fascinated by background videos that we see in webpages like https://www.laitkor.com/ , I wanted to develop something similar, but this time I to get the video from Youtube. How can I do it? 
P.S. The video should play automatically.

Comment: Please don't do that.  It's a) annoying as hell and b) very unfair on people with capped bandwidth allowances.

Comment: Actually it is my project, just in order to beautify, the website is not for public usage.

Comment: This question is **too broad**, not enough specific.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to embed a YouTube video as a webpage background:

```
<div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: -999;">
  <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" src="https://youtube.com/embed/[videoID]?autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1">
  </iframe>
</div>
```